# Using TypeScript, JSS with React throws `type is unassignable` for some css properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, jss

I'm new to TypeScript. I have a project created via `create-react-app` with TypeScript on board. Also I'm using JSS there.
At some point I found out that some CSS properties throw an error.

For example, here are `pointerEvents` and `position`. Any time I use them, I get an error.

```
(42,28): Argument of type '{ placeholder: { pointerEvents: string; }; wrapper: { '& select': { position: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<"wrapper" | "placeholder", CSSProperties> | StyleCreator<"wrapper" | "placeholder", {}>'.
Type '{ placeholder: { pointerEvents: string; }; wrapper: { '& select': { position: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleCreator<"wrapper" | "placeholder", {}>'.
Type '{ placeholder: { pointerEvents: string; }; wrapper: { '& select': { position: string; }; }; }' provides no match for the signature '(theme: {}): Record<"wrapper" | "placeholder", CSSProperties>'.
```

Replacing `pointerEvents` with `'pointer-events'` did the trick. But there's no way doing this with the `position` property.

So I actually have to either solve this issue or find a workaround.

Comment: If you have proper contextual typing in place, it shouldn't be necessary to annotate fields like `'absolute' as 'absolute'`.  If you'd be interested in my help to find a better solution, please add sufficient code to reproduce the original problem to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the easiest way I found is having the file containing styles to be a `tsx` file and assign properties like this:

```
classname: {
  position: 'absolute' as 'absolute',
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Can you explain why is there a need for this?

Comment: I can't, because I'm not... so well informed on the TypeScript mechanics. My guess is that there's either some clash of types or on the contrary not all types are in place and TypeScript is not pleased.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a very weird typing bug... But this will work like so:
You can create a Position enum, and just use it.

```
export enum Position {
   absolute = 'absolute',
   fixed = 'fixed',
   relative = 'relative',
   unset = 'unset',
   static = 'static',
   sticky = 'sticky'
   //... more position options here ...
}
```

Then you can just use this enum:

```
classname: {
   position: Position.absolute,
}
```